# The AMF response data structure called from ExtJS is different from that called from Flex

Tags: apache-flex, extjs, extjs5, blazeds, amf

I'm trying to use ExtJS5.1.2 as a front-end to replace Flex3 UI.
I heard that ExtJS can use AMF. I tested calling AMF from ExtJS, and it was success.

I expected it returns the same response as AMF+Flex3. But it didn't.
The response it called from ExtJS is slower and heavy than Flex.

**What I tested:**
Get 10000 records from Oracle DB and show it at DataGrid.

**The data size:**
13.1MB(ExtJS)
2.6MB(Flex3)

I saw the responses at Firebug.
[image]
[image]
The binary response is garbling, but it looks that the data structures are different.

**in ExtJS5.1.2**
The field names appeared every record.

POST request

```
������foo.getTestRecords�/1ÿÿÿÿ
����
```

POST response

```
������/1/onResult��ÿÿÿÿ�!flex.messaging.io.ArrayCollection�source
��'�modules.entity.APR361�SEQNO�    APM20HSEQ�KOCHGCD�HVPNO�FGAINO�TORYOKBN�NOTE1�MSIZE3
�0�SECKBN�MSIZE2�0�MSIZE1�0�REQFL�SKSEQNO�DJKBN�1�PCLS�1�ZUBAN�GACD�    HUNITNONM
�SRCLS�502�PYVPNO�0�ZBNHCNT�DSPSEQ�YOSETU�PVPUNIT�  APR363SEQ�UWSID�25803�PHKADOFL
�PBANNO�SECHGCD�PGDNM�PVLIN�0�APR36SEQ�892999�PJVSEQ�BA00010G0090�ITEMKB�GKBN�LINECD
�HKS�ZAICD�PVJAN�NYCHGCD�IPRGID�PA012X�PEND�0�FVPNO�0�PSYDATBt×oÏ���MKCD�PPRKBN2
�0�PPRKBN1�0�ISEQ�893000�PPRKBN3�0�TOSOCLO2�TOSOCLO1�PGDOHCLS�TOSOCLO3�SGVJAN�2621
�UPRGID�PA014X�IDATBtø5 Î��PPRDAT2�PPRDAT1�COMKBN�BUNCNT�PPRDAT3�ICHGCD�EMORI�NXGKBN
�GAOHCLS�PPRBSU3�PPRBSU2�ITEMOPE�PVCNT�WARI�B�TIM�20151019140515920�    GENCHKDAT�VISEQ
�1343�SEC�NNOTE�    APR362SEQ�UCHGCD�1053�MSGGRPID�PPRBSU1� APR361SEQ�HCNT�DDAT�SYUZUJK
�HINKB�UDATBuçË¯��WRKPTN�00�MCOMSEQ�LVL�MKNM�PVPNO�0�   APM21HSEQ�1018811�
SKKKSEREDA�A0010�BHCLS�PXFL�PLOT�PPRBAT1�GANM�PPRBAT2�CNCOMSEQ�RGENZU�ZAINM�NOTE10
�NOTE7�NOTE6�DFLG�0�CAMKBN�NOTE9�IWSID�6102�NOTE8�TOSOPRO�NOTE3�NOTE2�PPRBAT3
�NOTE5�NOTE4�PEYDATBtãýOØ����   �modules.entity.APR361�SEQNO�   APM20HSEQ�KOCHGCD�HVPNO
�FGAINO�TORYOKBN�NOTE1�MSIZE3�SECKBN�MSIZE2�MSIZE1�REQFL�SKSEQNO�DJKBN�0�PCLS
�2�ZUBAN�GACD�  HUNITNONM�SRCLS�503�PYVPNO�0�ZBNHCNT�DSPSEQ�YOSETU�PVPUNIT� APR363SEQ
�1064563�UWSID�7823�PHKADOFL�PBANNO�SECHGCD�PGDNM�PVLIN�0�APR36SEQ�1064307�PJVSEQ
�BA00013G0010�ITEMKB�GKBN�LINECD�HKS�ZAICD�PVJAN�NYCHGCD�IPRGID�PA014X�PEND�0�FVPNO
�0�PSYDAT�MKCD�PPRKBN2�0�PPRKBN1�0�ISEQ�1064567�PPRKBN3�0�TOSOCLO2�TOSOCLO1�PGDOHCLS
�TOSOCLO3�SGVJAN�1123�UPRGID�PA025X�IDATBtà¨ÈÆ���PPRDAT2�PPRDAT1�COMKBN�BUNCNT�
PPRDAT3�ICHGCD�EMORI�NXGKBN�GAOHCLS�PPRBSU3�PPRBSU2�ITEMOPE�PVCNT�WARI�B�TIM�20150803092306612
�   GENCHKDAT�VISEQ�1691�SEC�NNOTE� APR362SEQ�UCHGCD�EMORI�MSGGRPID�PPRBSU1�    APR361SEQ
�HCNT�DDAT�SYUZUJK�HINKB�UDATBtâÙh���WRKPTN�00�MCOMSEQ�LVL�MKNM�PVPNO�0�    APM21HSEQ
�1018657�
SKKKSEREDA�BHCLS�1�PXFL�PLOT�PPRBAT1�GANM�PPRBAT2�CNCOMSEQ�RGENZU�ZAINM�NOTE10
�NOTE7�NOTE6�DFLG�0�CAMKBN�NOTE9�IWSID�7447�NOTE8�TOSOPRO�NOTE3�NOTE2�PPRBAT3
�NOTE5�NOTE4�PEYDAT��   �modules.entity.APR361�SEQNO�000100�    APM20HSEQ�KOCHGCD�HVPNO�
FGAINO�TORYOKBN�NOTE1�MSIZE3�0�SECKBN�MSIZE2�0�MSIZE1�0�REQFL�0�SKSEQNO�000100
�DJKBN�0�PCLS�3�ZUBAN�GACD� HUNITNONM�SRCLS�505�PYVPNO�2�ZBNHCNT�DSPSEQ�10�YOSETU
�PVPUNIT�01�    APR363SEQ�UWSID�PHKADOFL�0�PBANNO�00�SECHGCD�PGDNM�æ©ç¨®åï½ï½ï½
ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï
½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï¿¥�PVLIN�1�APR36SEQ�1064307�PJVSEQ�BA00013G0010�ITEMKB�0�GKBN
�G�LINECD�HKS�ZAICD�PVJAN�999000�NYCHGCD�IPRGID�PD230S�PEND�0�FVPNO�0�PSYDAT�
MKCD�PPRKBN2�0�PPRKBN1�0�ISEQ�1064589�PPRKBN3�0�TOSOCLO2�TOSOCLO1�PGDOHCLS�0�TOSOCLO3
�SGVJAN�1123�UPRGID�IDATBtà©bV��PPRDAT2�PPRDAT1�COMKBN�BUNCNT�PPRDAT3�ICHGCD�
EMORI�NXGKBN�1�GAOHCLS�PPRBSU3�PPRBSU2�ITEMOPE�PVCNT�1�WARI�B�TIM�20150803092306612
�   GENCHKDAT�VISEQ�1700�SEC�NNOTE� APR362SEQ�UCHGCD�MSGGRPID�PPRBSU1�  APR361SEQ�1064569
�HCNT�0�DDAT�SYUZUJK�HINKB�UDAT�WRKPTN�00�MCOMSEQ�LVL�0�MKNM�PVPNO�0�   APM21HSEQ
�1018657�
```

**in Flex3**
The field names appeared once.

POST request

```
�����null�/10��,
���
Oflex.messaging.messages.RemotingMessageoperation
sourcedestinationtimestamp  bodymessageIdclientIdtimeToLiveheadersgetTestRecords
foo�    I92F7BB91-48E7-EB8E-D6A3-B69C86CDD6D8IDD3DCC46-C0C1-F47D-8317-4163090A7318�
DSEndpoint
my-amf  DSIdIDD392F8D-20AF-9878-D0A1-9BEE2CFD8DB0
```

POST response

```
�����/10/onResult��ÿÿÿÿ
Uflex.messaging.messages.AcknowledgeMessagetimestampheaders bodycorrelationIdmessageIdtimeToLive
clientIddestinationBubSr0�

Cflex.messaging.io.ArrayCollection  
#+modules.entity.APR361SEQNOAPM20HSEQKOCHGCDHVPNO
FGAINOTORYOKBNNOTE1
MSIZE3
SECKBN
MSIZE2
MSIZE1REQFLSKSEQNODJKBN PCLSZUBAN   GACDHUNITNONMSRCLS
PYVPNOZBNHCNT
DSPSEQ
YOSETUPVPUNITAPR363SEQUWSIDPHKADOFL
PBANNOSECHGCDPGDNMPVLINAPR36SEQ
PJVSEQ
ITEMKB  GKBN
LINECDZAICDPVJANNYCHGCD
IPRGID  PENDFVPNO
PSYDAT  MKCDPPRKBN2PPRKBN1  ISEQPPRKBN3TOSOCLO2TOSOCLO1PGDOHCLSTOSOCLO3
SGVJAN
UPRGID  IDATPPRDAT2PPRDAT1
COMKBN
BUNCNTPPRDAT3
ICHGCD
NXGKBNGAOHCLSPPRBSU3PPRBSU2ITEMOPEPVCNT WARITIMGENCHKDATVISEQSECNNOTEAPR362SEQ
UCHGCDMSGGRPIDPPRBSU1APR361SEQ  HCNT    DDATSYUZUJKHINKB    UDAT
WRKPTNMCOMSEQLVL    MKNMPVPNOAPM21HSEQSKKKSEREDABHCLS   PXFL    PLOTPPRBAT1 GANMPPRBAT2CNCOMSEQ
RGENZUZAINM
NOTE10NOTE7NOTE6    DFLG
CAMKBNNOTE9IWSIDNOTE8TOSOPRONOTE3NOTE2PPRBAT3NOTE5NOTE4
PEYDAT0zz1|502z25803z
892999BA00010G0090HKS
PA012XzzBt×oÏ��zz
893000z 2621
PA014XBtø5 Î�EMORIB#20151019140515920   1343    1053BuçË¯�00z
1018811A0010z   6102BtãýOØ��

z2503z1064563   7823z1064307BA00013G0010zzz
z1064567z   1123
PA025XBtà¨ÈÆ��#20150803092306612    1691BtâÙh��z1018657
|z  7447


000100zzzz<z3505"1001z-æ©ç¨®åï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½
ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï
½ï½ï½ï½ï½ï¿¥|*,zG
999000
PD230Szzzz1064589zz0Btà©bV�||4  17001064569z
zz8"zz  7452


000200z>zzzVz> MCM-002864@420DzCæº¶ãã¼ãã§ã¼ã³ãï
¼¢ï¼«ï¼´"*,z
002864Lzzzz1064590zz0Btà©b��4P1064592Rz
zï¼³ï¼³ï¼ï¼ï¼z8"zzT
```

**The question:**
In spite of both are calling same AMF, why are the responses different?
I need lightweight response like a Flex+AMF if possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

I'm using Ext JS 5.1.2, BlazeDS3, Tomcat6, Adobe Flex3.4.

**Updated: Nov 04 16:05(JST)**
I've read the source code of Ext.direct.AmfRemotingProvider and discovered this.

```
if (me.binary) {
    encoder = new Ext.data.amf.Encoder( {format: 0}); // AMF message sending always uses AMF0   Here!!
    // encode packet
    encoder.writeAmfPacket(amfHeaders, amfMessages);
    request.binaryData = encoder.bytes;
    request.binary = true; // Binary response
    request.headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/x-amf'};
} else {
    encoder = new Ext.data.amf.XmlEncoder();
    // encode packet
    encoder.writeAmfxRemotingPacket(amfMessages[0]);
    request.xmlData = encoder.body;
}
```

AmfRemotingProvider uses **AMF0**.
To be honest, I don't understand much about what's the difference between AMF0 and AMF3.
Anyway I'm doubting there and researching how to use AMF3 from ExtJS.

---

**The common Java code**

```
public List<APR361> getTestRecords() throws DAOException, IOException {

    List<APR361> list = new ArrayList<APR361>();
    Connection c = null;
    PreparedStatement ps = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String w_sql = "";

    try {
        w_sql = "SELECT A.* FROM APR361 A WHERE ROWNUM<10001";

        c = ConnectionHelper.getConnection();
        ps = c.prepareStatement(w_sql);

        rs = ps.executeQuery();

        while (rs.next()) {
            list.add(new APR361(
                    rs.getString("ISEQ"),
                    rs.getString("TIM"),
                    rs.getString("DFLG"),
                    rs.getString("VISEQ"),
                    rs.getTimestamp("IDAT"),
                    rs.getString("IWSID"),
                    rs.getString("IPRGID"),
                    rs.getString("ICHGCD"),
                    rs.getTimestamp("UDAT"),
                    rs.getString("UWSID"),
                    rs.getString("UPRGID"),
                    rs.getString("UCHGCD"),
                    rs.getTimestamp("DDAT"),
                    rs.getString("LINECD"),
                    rs.getString("APR36SEQ"),
                    rs.getString("PJVSEQ"),
                    rs.getString("SRCLS"),
                    rs.getString("PCLS"),
                    rs.getString("BHCLS"),
                    rs.getString("PVLIN"),
                    rs.getString("PVCNT"),
                    rs.getString("PLOT"),
                    rs.getString("REQFL"),
                    rs.getString("PXFL"),
                    rs.getString("DJKBN"),
                    rs.getString("APR362SEQ"),
                    rs.getString("APR361SEQ"),
                    rs.getString("APR363SEQ"),
                    rs.getString("SEQNO"),
                    rs.getString("SKSEQNO"),
                    rs.getString("DSPSEQ"),
                    rs.getString("HCNT"),
                    rs.getString("BUNCNT"),
                    rs.getString("PVJAN"),
                    rs.getString("PGDOHCLS"),
                    rs.getString("PGDNM"),
                    rs.getString("WRKPTN"),
                    rs.getString("APM20HSEQ"),
                    rs.getString("APM21HSEQ"),
                    rs.getString("LVL"),
                    rs.getString("HINKB"),
                    rs.getString("SGVJAN"),
                    rs.getString("PYVPNO"),
                    rs.getString("PVPUNIT"),
                    rs.getTimestamp("PSYDAT"),
                    rs.getTimestamp("PEYDAT"),
                    rs.getString("PHKADOFL"),
                    rs.getString("WARI"),
                    rs.getString("SEC"),
                    rs.getString("MSGGRPID"),
                    rs.getString("HVPNO"),
                    rs.getString("NXGKBN"),
                    rs.getString("GACD"),
                    rs.getString("GAOHCLS"),
                    rs.getString("GANM"),
                    rs.getString("PVPNO"),
                    rs.getString("FVPNO"),
                    rs.getString("PEND"),
                    rs.getString("PPRKBN1"),
                    rs.getString("PPRBAT1"),
                    rs.getTimestamp("PPRDAT1"),
                    rs.getString("PPRBSU1"),
                    rs.getString("PPRKBN2"),
                    rs.getString("PPRBAT2"),
                    rs.getTimestamp("PPRDAT2"),
                    rs.getString("PPRBSU2"),
                    rs.getString("PPRKBN3"),
                    rs.getString("PPRBAT3"),
                    rs.getTimestamp("PPRDAT3"),
                    rs.getString("PPRBSU3"),
                    rs.getString("ITEMKB"),
                    rs.getString("ZUBAN"),
                    rs.getString("MKCD"),
                    rs.getString("MKNM"),
                    rs.getString("ZAICD"),
                    rs.getString("ZAINM"),
                    rs.getString("SECKBN"),
                    rs.getString("MSIZE1"),
                    rs.getString("MSIZE2"),
                    rs.getString("MSIZE3"),
                    rs.getString("RGENZU"),
                    rs.getString("FGAINO"),
                    rs.getString("TORYOKBN"),
                    rs.getString("GKBN"),
                    rs.getString("PBANNO"),
                    rs.getString("HUNITNONM"),
                    rs.getString("NNOTE"),
                    rs.getString("SKKKSEREDA"),
                    rs.getTimestamp("GENCHKDAT"),
                    rs.getString("KOCHGCD"),
                    rs.getString("SECHGCD"),
                    rs.getString("NYCHGCD"),
                    rs.getString("SYUZUJK"),
                    rs.getString("ITEMOPE"),
                    rs.getString("TOSOPRO"),
                    rs.getString("TOSOCLO1"),
                    rs.getString("TOSOCLO2"),
                    rs.getString("TOSOCLO3"),
                    rs.getString("NOTE1"),
                    rs.getString("NOTE2"),
                    rs.getString("NOTE3"),
                    rs.getString("NOTE4"),
                    rs.getString("NOTE5"),
                    rs.getString("NOTE6"),
                    rs.getString("NOTE7"),
                    rs.getString("NOTE8"),
                    rs.getString("NOTE9"),
                    rs.getString("NOTE10"),
                    rs.getString("ZBNHCNT"),
                    rs.getString("CAMKBN"),
                    rs.getString("YOSETU"),
                    rs.getString("MCOMSEQ"),
                    rs.getString("CNCOMSEQ"),
                    rs.getString("COMKBN")
                    ));
        }

    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        throw new DAOException(e);
    } finally {
        try {
            if (rs != null) rs.close();
            if (ps != null) ps.close();
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        ConnectionHelper.close(c);
    }
    return list;
}
```

**Call AMF from ExtJS**

```
Ext.Direct.addProvider({
    "url":"http://127.0.0.1:8400/myTestApp/messagebroker/amf", // URL for the AMFEndpoint
    "type":"amfremoting",
    "endpoint": "my-amf", // the name of the AMFEndpoint channel as defined in the server's services-config.xml
    "binary": true, // chooses AMF encoding
    "actions":{
        "foo":[{ // name of the destination as defined in remoting-config.xml on the server
            "name":"getTestRecords", // method name of the method to call
            "len":0 // number of parameters
        }]
    }
});

foo.getTestRecords((function(provider, response) {
    var store = Ext.getStore("baz");
    store.loadData(provider);
}));
```

**Call AMF from Flex3**

```
public var srv: RemoteObject;
public var arrTestRecords: ArrayCollection;

public function setSRV(): void
{
    srv = new RemoteObject();
    srv.showBusyCursor = true;
    srv.destination = "foo";

    var messageUrl:String = "http://{server.name}:{server.port}/myTestApp/messagebroker/amf";
    var cs:ChannelSet = new ChannelSet();
    cs.addChannel( new AMFChannel("my-amf", messageUrl) ); 

    srv.channelSet = cs;
}

public function getTest(nextfunc: Function=null): void
{
    var token: AsyncToken = srv.getTestRecords();
    token.addResponder(new AsyncResponder(

        // on success
        function(e:ResultEvent, obj:Object=null):void
        {
            var w_arr: ArrayCollection;
            var i: int;
            w_arr = new ArrayCollection(); 
            w_arr = e.result;

            arrTestRecords = new ArrayCollection();
            for (i=0; i<w_arr.length; i++) {
                arrTestRecords.addItem(APR361(w_arr[i]));
            }

            arrTestRecords.refresh();

            grid.dataProvider = arrTestRecords;
        },

        // NG
        TokenFaultEvent
    ));
}
```

**Updated: Feb 02 2016 11:35(JST)**
I  tried to use Node.js & node-oracledb driver with gzip compression instead of using the AMF & BlazeDS.
The response data size was 900KB!

ExtJS+Node.js(900KB) vs Flex3+AMF3(2.6MB)

However the AMF3 still about 2x faster than Node.js.

Comment: Of course you're getting different results.  You're making very different requests.  `������foo.getTestRecords�/1ÿÿÿÿ` vs. `�����null�/10��,` with `Oflex.messaging.messages.RemotingMessageoperation
sourcedestinationtimestamp  bodymessageIdclientIdtimeToLiveheadersgetTestRecords` in there, too.

Comment: Yes, if ExtJS could call same request as Flex, probably it returns same response.
I think there are 2 issues.

1. Is it possible to call same POST request from ExtJS?
2. If the above is possible, can ExtJS parse the response?

Comment: I've been researching how to change the request for a few days, however there isn't much information about AMF with ExtJS.
(Due to using AMF from ExtJS needs commercial license, or due to only a few ExtJS users adopt AMF(maybe they are also emigrants from Flex).)